# Angular ng-model in `<select>` change function find dynamically

Tags: angularjs

Using Angular 1.x I have two groups of select boxes, both call a function on change:

```
ng-click="checkOneOptionSelected()"
```

In my controller I would like to know which group of select boxes called the function:

```
$scope.checkOneOptionSelected = function(value){ 

      .. do something...

}
```

Is there a way to get the value of ng-model dynamically without passing a string as a parameter, perhaps using 'this' or similar. HArdcoding the value as a param will work but feels hacky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `ng-model` directive, the code should use the `ng-change` directive instead of `ng-click`.

```
<select ng-model="$ctrl.sel1" ng-change="$ctrl.updateSel('sel1',$ctrl.sel1)"
        ng-options="...">
  <option value="">Select sel1</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="$ctrl.sel2" ng-change="$ctrl.updateSel('sel2',$ctrl.sel2)"
        ng-options="...">
  <option value="">Select sel2</option>
</select>
```

To share the same update function, simply add arguments to indicate the source of the change.

```
this.updateSel = function (id, val) {
    console.log(id,val);
    //...
};
```

The `ng-click` directive fights with the `ngModelController`. The `ng-change` directive uses the [$viewChangeListeners](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$viewChangeListeners) property of the `ngModelController`. The `ngChange` expression is only evaluated when a change in the input value causes a new value to be committed to the model.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-change Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange).

Comment: @georgewg when using ng-change I found that when I read the length, ie vd.checkbox_1.length the value returned was the value prior to the click. So when I clicked the first checkbox the length was given as 0 and not 1. ng-click returned the correct value.

Comment: It works in this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/jhFowIlLdYi3YHj4qrmm?p=preview). There must be more going on in your `<select>` boxes than shows in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You may pass builtin `$event` object (mentioned in [ng-click reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) in arguments), which is [iQuery event object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

```
ng-click="checkOneOptionSelected($event)"
```

Then use its `target` field to reason about what was clicked:

```
$scope.checkOneOptionSelected = function(event){ 

      .. do something with event.target, e.g...
      if(event.target.id == 'Option123') {
          ...
      }

}
```

Comment: since the suggested method would require hard coding of the possible options in the controller I don't think it offers any advantage of passing the id or ng-model value as a param. Maybe what I am looking for is not possible.

Comment: Agree, no advantages over passing some kind of `id` directly.